# Export data from Kafka to Oracle

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, sink

I am trying to export data from Kafka to Oracle db. I've searched related questions and web but could not understand that we need a platform (confluent etc.. ) or not. I'd been read the link below but it's not clear enough.
https://docs.confluent.io/3.2.2/connect/connect-jdbc/docs/sink_connector.html

 So, what we actually need to export data without 3rd party platform? 
 Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know Kafka. But, if it is a one-time-job and you can export data from Kafka to a CSV file, then you could "import" it into Oracle using SQL*Loader or having the CSV file as an external table. No 3rd party involved.

Comment: @Littlefoot no we will be using it constantly and there will be huge data

Comment: There is a series of blog posts covering Kafka connect usage in more detail, try [Simplest Useful Kafka Connect Data Pipeline](https://www.confluent.io/blog/simplest-useful-kafka-connect-data-pipeline-world-thereabouts-part-1/) or for more in-depth [Kafka Connect Deep Dive – JDBC Source Connector](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/) and [here in this git](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/tree/master/connect-jdbc) you can also find an example Oracle config you can play with as well.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you mean by "third-party" here

What you linked to is *Kafka Connect*, which is **Apache 2.0 Licensed and open source.**

Kafka Connect is a plugin ecosystem, you install connectors individually, written by anyone, or write your own, just like any other Java dependency (i.e. a third-party)

The JDBC connector just happens to be *maintained by Confluent.* and you can configure the [Confluent Hub CLI](https://docs.confluent.io/current/confluent-hub/client.html) 
to install within any Kafka Connect distribution (or use Kafka Connect Docker images from Confluent)

---

Alternatively, you use Apache Spark, Flink, Nifi, and many other Kafka Consumer libraries to read data and then start an Oracle transaction per record batch

Or you can explore non-JVM kafka libraries as well and use a language you're more familiar with doing Oracle operations with

Comment: I am not sure how many will write own connectors. We are on a project opting for spark, kafka integration.

Comment: Not everyone has a Spark cluster. Why should writing a connector be any harder than writing Spark code? You get a list of records and you map them into a jdbc request and that's really it, it doesn't have to as generic as Confluent's one is @theblue

Comment: Point taken. Happy new year.